# Phabricator: Arcanist : arc diff --update : No Changes Found

Tags: command-line, updates, revision, phabricator

I recently started using phabricator. I am using the Arcanist CLI to submit the differential to phabricator. It was working fine until yesterday and today it throws an error whenever i am trying to create a new revision or update an existing one.

This is the command i am using to update revision `D3`

```
arc diff --update D3
```

and after i put in the comments, it throws the following exception

```
Linting...
No lint engine configured for this project.
Running unit tests...
No unit test engine is configured for this project.
Usage Exception: No changes found. (Did you specify the wrong commit range?)
```

you guys have any idea what might be wrong ?

Comment: did you ever figure out what was causing this?  I have the same issue on a windows box, but have no idea.

Comment: I do not exactly remember the cause but it was to do something with the `libphutil`'s version mismatch so i installed the correct version and that solved the issue.

Comment: cool, thats a good spot to start looking....how/where did you find the `libphutil` version?  Mine was pulled down from git when I got arc recently?

Comment: @Amyth: could you please help me to install Arcanist... I am not able to understand from documentation how to install. Thanks

Comment: This should not have been closed. It is certainly NOT off topic. Very frustrating when you try to get help on SO and people close topics when they shouldn't.

Comment: @DavidS Nominate it for reopen.

Comment: still seeing this today ~ when trying merge-back release branch into develop, no idea how to fix, unless turn off code-review completely, disaster ~!

Answer (score 8):

You didn't specify a commit range as the message says.

Try:

```
arc diff HEAD~ --update D3
```

Where HEAD~ should be the commits you wish to push to the revision

Comment: Without Head argument arcanist usually takes all changes.